# How do i use vfs_readdir in linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, system, kernel, call

I'm trying to use a system call to display the contents of a directory. I've been pointed in the direction of vfs_readdir, but I have no clue of how to use it or what to pass to it to get the contents of a directory. All I want to do is be able to list files in a directory similar to how ls works. (I eventually intend to store this in some sort of buffer, but for now just being able to print the contents of a dir would be enough).

Comment: Are you writing kernel-level code?

Comment: Yes. Writing my own system call(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have to open the directory using filp_open.

For the "flags" argument, you proably need to put some combination of the LOOKUP_ flags listed in include/linux/namei.h

You can see what build_open_flags does here: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.5/fs/open.c#L876 to provide flags to filp_open.

As far as I know, filp_open IS the correct way of opening a file in kernel-space. However, doing so is discouraged.

Provided you do so from the context of a "normal" thread belonging to a user process, I think you will be ok.